# When checkbox is True,Date field is Editable && if checkbox is False, Date field is Hide/Readonly in aura controller

Tags: lightning

Hi pls find my requirement , When checkbox is True ,then Date field should be Visible if not then Date field should be Readonly /Invisible
pls find my analysis below :

1. In Page layout, Date field is Readonly .
   In comp:

   ```
    <aura:attribute name = "FirstContractYearEndDate" type = "Date"/>  (Date Field)
   ```

In aura cotroller :

```
var checkbox = false;
var SFYI = component.get("v.SFYI");  (Checkbox field)
if(SFYI){
 component.set("v.FirstContractYearEndDate",true);
}
else
{
component.set("v.FirstContractYearEndDate",false);
}
```

But its not working ,how to hide/readonly the Date field  when checkbox is false

Answer (score 0):

Use aura:if condition to achieve that requirement.

//I have written java script skelton to you

```
   method:function(comp,ev,helper){

  //Passing checkbox value: comp.find("check").get("v.value");  here check is checkbox Id

var checkbox=comp.find("check").get("v.value"); 
if(checkbox) 
{
comp.set("v.datehide",true);
}else
{
 comp.set(v.datehide",false);
} }
```

//=============================================

```
      <aura:attribute name = "datehide" type ="boolean"/>  
         <aura:if isTrue="{!v.datehide}">
 <!---Display Date field -->
<aura:set attribute="else">
 <!-- Hide it  -->
</aura:set>
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response.  But in my code, <!---Display Date field --> is not in aura component. its added in page layout only . ( Not added in component / code level) .Retrive from page layout with  help of Handler class in Controller .  For this reason , i am unable to complete this . Pls let me know do you have any idea how to acheive this

Comment: How you will hide in page layout ??? I didnt get your question  not clearly... lets wait for others answer.